# Laravel unique validation

Tags: php, laravel

How can I perform this migration rule to `laravel` validation rule

```
$table->unique(['field_1', 'field_2']);
```

Lets say that i have a categories table with `title`, `slug` and `category_type` fields.

So what I want is something like this:

```
Slug             Category_type
foo              Blog

foo              News           => Pass the validation
foo              Blog           => Return back with error...
```

so far I tried this but I still got no result?

```
$rules = [
            'slug' => 'required|max:70|unique:categories,slug,null,id,category_type,' . Blog::class . '|regex:/(^[A-Za-z-_ ]+$)+/',
            'title' => 'required|max:70',
        ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you have given is correct,

```
unique:categories,field_1,null,id,field_2,field_2_value
```

ref,
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique

But remember `Blog::class` returns full class path.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up mate, I wasn't on fully attention that in which controller I am.