# How to validate if user already exists?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to validate if it already exists in the DB, so then show an error message. But I am always getting `user already exists` in both cases. How can I fix it?

Below is my code:

```php
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $request_data = $request->all();
    $customer_ids = $request_data['ids'];
    $campaigns_id = $request_data['campaigns_id'];

    $customer_id_array = explode(',', $customer_ids);
    $whereIn = $customer_id_array;
    $check_customer = Participant::where('id', $campaigns_id)->whereIn('customer_id', $whereIn)->get();

    if (!empty($check_customer)) {
        return ['code' => 402, 'status' => 'error', 'data' => $check_customer, 'message' => 'Customer Already Exists'];
    }

    foreach ($customer_id_array as $key => $value) {
        $participantObj = new Participant;

        $participantObj['customer_id'] = $value;
        $participantObj->campaign_id = $campaigns_id;
        // $participantObj->pin_number =  $this->randomNumber(3).''.$key;

        $data = $participantObj;
        $data ->save();
    }

    return['code' => 200, 'status' => 'success'];
}
```

Comment: You are always going to get `402`, as `->get();` will always return a `Collection`, so that is `true` when you do `!empty($check_customer)`. Read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique) as it is explained there...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel unique validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971685/laravel-unique-validation)

Comment: but i have to satisfy both the conditions. $check_customer = Participant::where('id', $campaigns_id)->whereIn('customer_id', $whereIn)->get(); .I think i this unqiue check is requied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
if (!empty($check_customer)) {
```

to

```
if ($check_customer->isNotEmpty()) {
```